# Multiple instance of class versus array Java

Tags: java, oop

My question which of the following examples represents the right practice ? 
What are the advantages and downsides of these approaches. 
Is there another(right) way to achieve this?

Let's say I have class

```
public class Person {

    private String name;

    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String print() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

And use of class like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();
        people.add(new Person("Jane Doe"));
        System.out.println(people.get(0).print());
}
```

And then another way to do this:

```
public class Persons {

    private ArrayList<String> persons;

    public Persons() {
        persons = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    public void putPerson(String name) {
         persons.add(name);
    }

    public String print(int id) {
        return this.persons.get(id);
    }
}
```

And use of that:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Persons persons = new Persons();
        persons.putPerson("John Doe");
        System.out.println(persons.print(0));
    }
```

EDIT:

Assume I have 10 000 of these persons. 
Is there any downside to creating 10,000 instances of the class?

Comment: And what is your actual question? If it's right or wrong to make your own collections? (`Persons` in this case would be a collection that should only be able to contain `Person` objects)

Comment: Is there any downsides of making these collections?

Comment: @Evus it's fine provided you have only one field for `Person`, try adding multiple fields and different sub-types.

Comment: I think this is either optinion-based or would be a better fit for the "programmers" site. IMHO, unless you (a) add more specialized methods to the `Persons` class, or (b) want to restrict some methods, e.g. _removing_ persons, a basic (typed) list is sufficient, and ultimately clearer. Also, you don't have to re-expose all that list-functionality.

Comment: I close question. Because it can be oppinion based and i my question Is  inexact.

Comment: @Evus If you have a need to have a Collection that you only want to be able to store object `X` in, and you perform some specific task to get some data (your case the `print()` function, for example) then it can be quite useful. If it helps you keep your code [DRY] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), do it. But check @tobias_k s comment as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer the first way because there is a rare need to create a wrapper class for keeping a collection (like `Persons` -> `Person`). It makes sense if the class `Persons` gets renamed to a `Company`/`Community`, which contains a `List` of workers/persons and provides specific operations over this list.

```
public String showAllMembers() { ... }
public void notifyAllMembers() { ... }
```

Also, the second way breaks the [Single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). It shouldn't take care about printing a person, the class is responsible for adding/removing them. The `Persons` can provide to you a specific `Person`, then you have to call a method `print()` on a given instance:

```
Persons persons = ...;
persons.getMember(10).print();
```

---

> Lets say i have 10 000 of these persons. Is there any downside to create 10 000 instance of class?

In any case, you will have to create 10000+ instances. Consider,

- `10000` `Person`s + a `List`
- `10000` `Person`s + a `Persons` + a `List`

Answer (score 1):

The first one is more object-oriented than the second, which becomes apparent as soon as you start adding more properties to a person.

For example, consider adding a date of birth to a person. When you have `class Person`, you modify the class, and everyone who has access to it will be able to get it. You will also be passing the date of birth with the `Person` object, so any method that takes `Person` as a parameter will have access to that person's date of birth:

```
static void displayPerson(Person p) {
    // Here, we can print both the name and the date of birth / age
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...
    displayPerson(people.get(0));
}
```

The second approach would require adding a parallel collection to the `Persons` class. All users of `Persons` would get access to date of birth, but unless a method takes the full collection as a parameter, it would have access to only the properties that the caller takes from the collection:

```
void displayPerson(String name) {
    // Here, we have no access to person's date of birth
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...
    displayPerson(persons.print(0));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java, **the first approach is the one to go with**. It is more in accordance with the OOP way of doing things.

While there is nothing structurally wrong with the second, it doesn't follow the OOP architecture. You may do this kind of operation in C.

In the first approach, you create a `Person` class which defines what a person is - its properties, methods, etc. This is the object in *Object oriented programming*. When you need a `Person`, you then instantiate one and add it to a list of people.

In the second, you create a array, essentially. You can then create an instance of it and fill in the properties you want. However, I see the following drawbacks for this approach:

- The object you're adding to the class doesn't exist anymore. Nowhere have you defined what a person is and what properties it has. These properties only exist in the values you add to the array. This can get very confusing and risky after a while.
- No getters and setters. Every operation to retrieve a specific property and update it will result in very complex and redundant iterations on your array. In addition, your class can potentially have a very large number of properties, and every time you want to update a property, you'll have to be very careful to get the right index of that property in the array. It's a recipe for disaster.
- Also, a `putPerson` method which just adds a value to the array? Cringy.

Short answer: don't do the second way, in Java, ever.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion example A is much easier to understand than B hence I would say code readability and maintainability wise it is better.

Reason is that for example B the `persons` structure actually involves composition of another structure `ArrayList` to accomplish generics which in example A, you have achieve it by declaring `List<Person>`.

Example B is also less flexible than A, because it is always a collection whereas example A you can simply use it as a `Person` and just plug it into different data structures available in Java. Example if you want to keep track of unique person, you can easily come out with a map that is keyed by `<name, Person>`, whereas example B would not be as clean because you will be doing something like `<name, Persons>` where each `persons` would only contain 1 person. Hence extensiblity wise may not be as great as the other one.

Also to me, A is more of the traditional way of doing object oriented because you are representing a real world object as a class whereas B is really just a wrapper of an object.

Obviously there can be a lot of arguments to this, but I'm happy with others input and critic about this answer.